# How to define a function which returns sum of functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to define a function which returns the sum of functions' calls in Python.

The important thing is it will return another ***function***, and not a *value*.

For example:

```
def sum_of_functions(func1, func2):
    output = func1 + func2
    return output

f1 = lambda x: x**2
f2 = lambda x: x

sum_functions = sum_of_functions(f1, f2)
type(sum_functions)
# function

sum_functions(2)
# 6
```

Of course, `+` is unsupported for functions, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a wrapping function or lambda:

```py
def sum_of_functions(func1, func2):
    return lambda x: func1(x) + func2(x)
```

Then you can call it directly or store it in a varialble:

```py
f1 = lambda x: x**2
f2 = lambda x: x

composed = sum_of_functions(f1, f2)
assert composed(2) == sum_of_functions(f1, f2)(2)
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of  using a function in it again?

Perhaps the reason why I couldn't find the answer even if I searched is because it was too easy.

Comment: The assertion is kinda pointless. If `x = y` then of course `x(2) == y(2)`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo ofc it is pointless, it just serves the porpoise of showing the point that the call can be chained....

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
def sum_functions(func1, func2):
    def inner(x):
        return func1(x) + func2(x)
    return inner

f1 = lambda x: x**2
f2 = lambda x: x

sum_of_functions = sum_functions(f1, f2)

type(sum_of_functions)
function

sum_of_functions(2)
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go on using lambda expressions! Pass the bounded variable into the two functions, sum them together, and return the lambda expression as a whole.

Define it as follows:

```py
def sum_of_functions(func1, func2):
    return lambda x: func1(x) + func2(x)
```

By the way, as far as I understand, what you really want calling `sum_of_functions` should be

```py
>>> func1 = lambda x: x ** 2
>>> func2 = lambda x: x
>>> ans = sum_of_functions(func1, func2)
>>> type(ans)
function
>>> ans(2)
6
```

right?